# Advice on how to model the part of the handle attached to the frypan

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to model a frypan handle:

[image: Reference image]

My idea was to model the part of the handle that lies on top of the frypan and the rest of the handle separately, and then somehow merge them. I used the shrinkwrap modifier to create the first part. When it came to merging with the rest, I tried using bridge function and merging vertices manually, but none of these approaches worked well (I attached the results I got). Any advice on modeling this shape would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here's my Blend file:

[image]

Comment: can you show wireframe versions of your two attempts, or, if possible, include your blend file? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: @MartyFouts added file with my bridge attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file you have posted, the 'bulge' is a shading artifact because some of the normals have gotten reversed.

My soultion was to enter edit mode; select all of the faces on the handle and then use SHIFT-N to recalculate normals:

[image: result of recalculating normals]

Otherwise your topology on both the pan and the handle looks very good.

**Addition**

Here's one way to start the handle if you wanted it to be part of the pan mesh:

- divide the pan in half so you only have to do each step once

[image: divide in half]

- add a mirror modifier above the subsurf modifier

[image: mirror modifier]

- add a loop cut so that you have a wide and narrow face to extrude

[image: add a loop cut]

- switch to face mode and extrude the two appropriate faces to create the attached part of the handle

[image: extrude]

but now you need extra geometry, in the form of loop cuts, to make it appear that the handle is separate. and you have some shading issues to resolve

[image: need for extra geometry]

In this case I would definitely use your approach and make the handle separate from the pan because of the issues I just mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! It's always great to learn how to solve problems that may come up in the future. I would be very grateful if you could answer one more question. I would like to know if the approach I have taken is acceptable. I had to put some effort into aligning the handle parts at the correct angle before bridging them together. It doesn't seem very convenient. It might have been worth making the handle as one connected mesh, but I didn't know how to make the end of the handle sit on the surface of the pan in this case.

Comment: Your approach worked and would work in the future. Alternately you could use the knife tool to cut a face in the pan and then extrude that face slightly, but that means adding extra geometry to the pan and that doesn't always work.  In the real world the handle would be separate and sometimes making things separate makes them easier to deal with.  When you want to add materials, say to make the handle aluminum and the pan cast iron it will be easier to do if they're separate.  It all depends on what you're going to use the model for.

Comment: My approach to getting a close fit would be 1: Always model separate parts as separate parts, unless you need to print, or something. 2. Make a duplicate of the pan, or part of it. Make cuts in the duplicate the right shape for the marrying end of the handle, without changing the curvature of the pan, and use that edge-loop to extrude, or bridge edge loops, out to other handle profiles. (Matching vertex counts).

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to guess the design as you only have one view, but you can begin with the drawing of the profile:

[image]

Then move up this part on Z:

[image]

Add a bit of topology:

[image]

Give it *Solidify* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your approach looks interesting. Could you explain the step "move up this part on Z" in a little more detail?

Comment: you lust select the edges and move them only on Z so that your topology doesn't change when on top view